# SQLITE raw query result not the same as in aSQLiteManager

Tags: android, sqlite, date, sql-order-by

I make the following query in SQLitemanager (SQL DB App for Android):

```
SELECT * FROM fahrer, fahrzeuge, nutzungsarten, fahrtenbuch WHERE fahrtenbuch.nutzungsart_id = nutzungsarten._id AND fahrtenbuch.fahrzeuge_id = fahrzeuge._id AND fahrtenbuch.fahrer_id = fahrer._id ORDER BY SUBSTR(fahrtenbuch.startdatum,7,4), SUBSTR(fahrtenbuch.startdatum,4,2), SUBSTR(fahrtenbuch.startdatum,1,2) ASC
```

The returned order is as expected. The date is correctly sorted by **dd.mm.yyyy**.

But when I execute the query in my **DB-Helper class**, the order is not the same.
In the DB-Helper class:

```
final String MY_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM fahrer, fahrzeuge, nutzungsarten, fahrtenbuch WHERE fahrtenbuch.nutzungsart_id = nutzungsarten._id AND fahrtenbuch.fahrzeuge_id = fahrzeuge._id AND fahrtenbuch.fahrer_id = fahrer._id ORDER BY SUBSTR(fahrtenbuch.startdatum,7,4), SUBSTR(fahrtenbuch.startdatum,4,2), SUBSTR(fahrtenbuch.startdatum,1,2) ASC";
return mDb.rawQuery(MY_QUERY, null);
```

In my activity:

---

```
Cursor curCSV = mDbHelper.fetchAllFahrtenbuchASC();
curCSV.moveToFirst();
while(curCSV.moveToNext()) 
{
   System.out.println("Date of entry: " +curCSV.getString(18));
} 

curCSV.close();
```

---

Does anyone know why this is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
curCSV.moveToFirst();
while(curCSV.moveToNext()) ...
```

skips over the first record.
Use instead:

```java
if (curCSV.moveToFirst())
    do {
        ...
    } while (curCSV.moveToNext());
```

Comment: No change with the do/while combination.
The Problem is not only the first entry.
It seems that the "ORDER BY" statement is completely ignored.

Comment: Oh Man. Figured it out. Caused of a copied part of a function, I was in the wrong one. Nevertheless I changed also my loop to your do/while.